# how to check that a property of an object is empty

Tags: powershell

I made a script that list disks with its corresponding partitions and volumes ,the problem that in most cases there is no volumes for specific partitions.

the issue appears in this command

```
Get-Volume -DriveLetter $partition.DriveLetter
```

as the following error is returned when there is no driveletter

```
Get-Volume : Invalid property 
At line:13 char:16
+  Write-Host ($(Get-Volume -DriveLetter $partition.DriveLetter <#-Erro ...
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (MSFT_Volume:ROOT/Microsoft/...age/MSFT_Volume) [Get-Volume], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041031,Get-Volume
```

I can't made a statement that checks whether the following object $partition.DriveLetter has value or not
I tried to use the following statement, but it didn't work.

```
if( $partition.DriveLetter.ToString() -ne $null)
if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace(partition.DriveLetter.ToString()))
```

I made a temp solution by adding "ErrorAction SilentlyContinue" in

```
Get-Volume -DriveLetter $partition.DriveLetter -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

the output of the script was as I wish ,attached below the script and output.

I need to make an if statement to check if $partition.DriveLetter ,any suggestions.

```
PS C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxxxxx> $disks = Get-Disk
Write-Output("Total number of disks is $($disks.length) ");
For ($i=0; $i -lt $disks.Length ; $i++)
 {
 Write-Output("Disk $($i) is selected now");
 $partitions = Get-Partition -DiskNumber $i | Select-Object DiskNumber,PartitionNumber,DriveLetter,IsActive,type,@{Name="Size, Gb"; Expression={[int]($_.Size/1GB)}}
 Write-Output("partitons in disk $($i)")
  ForEach($partition in $partitions)
 {
  
  Write-Host ($($partition) | Format-Table | Out-String)
 
 Write-Host ($(Get-Volume -DriveLetter $partition.DriveLetter -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)| Format-Table | Out-String)

 }

 }
```

the output is:

```
Total number of disks is 2 
Disk 0 is selected now
partitons in disk 0

DiskNumber PartitionNumber DriveLetter IsActive Type Size, Gb
---------- --------------- ----------- -------- ---- --------
         0               1           C     True IFS       100




DriveLetter FriendlyName FileSystemType DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatus SizeRemaining   Size
----------- ------------ -------------- --------- ------------ ----------------- -------------   ----
C           XXXXXXXX-C   NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                     75.87 GB 100 GB



Disk 1 is selected now
partitons in disk 1

DiskNumber PartitionNumber DriveLetter IsActive Type    Size, Gb
---------- --------------- ----------- -------- ----    --------
         1               3                False Unknown        0





DiskNumber PartitionNumber DriveLetter IsActive Type     Size, Gb
---------- --------------- ----------- -------- ----     --------
         1               1                False Reserved        0





DiskNumber PartitionNumber DriveLetter IsActive Type  Size, Gb
---------- --------------- ----------- -------- ----  --------
         1               2           D    False Basic      200




DriveLetter FriendlyName FileSystemType DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatus SizeRemaining      Size
----------- ------------ -------------- --------- ------------ ----------------- -------------      ----
D           XXXXXXXX-D   NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                    199.88 GB 199.98 GB
```

Comment: You might be overthinking this: `if($partition.DriveLetter){ Get-Volume ... }`

Comment: Alternatively without an if: `$partition | Where-Object DriveLetter | Get-Volume ...`

Comment: @MAthias thank you ,really I didn't know that ,I thought I should use an operator to make a condition ,
thanks for both of you Mathias and Zett42